# Get start date of the week for the month in the given date in Tableau

Tags: date, tableau-api

I am trying to get the weeknumber for a month from a give date.
using following method:

Created a calculated field for 'week of the year': as `A`

```
DATEPART('week',[Date],'monday')
```

created a calculated field for "week of start date" : as `B`

```
 DATEPART('week',DATETRUNC('month',[Date]),'monday')
```

Hence week =

```
 A-B+1
```

Also, I am calculating Week Start Date using:

```
DATETRUNC('week',[Date],'monday')
```

I am facing one issue:
For instance, date: 08/31/2020 ( This is monday)
This is showing as week 6 for August as well as week 1 for September which it should not show.
Week 1 for September should be 09/01/2020.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: How any function can return two values?  That is against the definition of a function! please show me the screenshot where you are getting two values for 08/31/2020. I am also unable to understand why do you want `week 1` for `09/01/2020` when the week is not starting on Monday?  Do you want the values as given in solution proposed by me? please check

Answer (score 1):

Create a calculated field 'desired result'

```
floor(DAY([Date])/7)+1
```

and you should be able to get what you want.  Please check on some sample records

[image]